# how to obtain output of shell script invoked from expect script?

Tags: ksh, expect

My requirement is that i have a tar file copied from a remote server i have to check it was copied properly using checksum . My problem is that i need 2 shell scripts: 1. to ssh into server obtain checksum value of file in server 2. script that obtains checksum of local file and compares the values of local and server file checksum. My problem is that the `print` statements in 2nd shell script do not print on screen. Here is what I've done:

### expect script:

```
set tarFile [lindex $argv 0]
log_user 0
spawn /home/bmc/login.sh
expect "password:"
send "pwd\r"
expect "]#"
sleep 60
send "md5sum $tarFile\r"
expect "]#"
set valfromserver $expect_out(buffer)
set vals [split $valfromserver "\n"]
set hashval [lindex $vals 1]
send "logout"
spawn /home/bmc/newscript.sh $tarFile $hashval
```

### the script for comparison of hash values

```
#!/bin/ksh
hashval=$(md5sum /repo/$USER/$1)
arr=($hashval)
if [[ $2 == ${arr[0]} ]]; then
    print "file on server and client are of same size"
else
    print "files not copied properly"
fi
```

Comment: Why do you need two scripts ? Hash comparison can be done in expect script itself.

Comment: Tried it but did not work out. Anyways thanks for the reply :)